# UI freezes when running program for searching files in whole system using C# Tasks

Tags: c#

I have written a small program which searches for some kind of files in whole syatem and after search is complete it shows the result in a list view but when I run this program my form freezes and i can not do anything.

Can someone please help in trying to fix the problem , below is the code I have written

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Security.AccessControl;


namespace SearchAndZipUtility
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private string _destFolder;
        private string _sourceToSearch = @"E:\New Books";
        private TaskScheduler schedular = TaskScheduler.Current;
        private CancellationTokenSource _ct = new CancellationTokenSource();
        private List<string> files = new List<string>();
        private string _selectedFileType;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            toolStripStatusInfo.Visible = false;
            btnZip.Enabled = false;
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            // bind file types to combo box
            PopulateComboList();
            if (cmbFileTypes.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                cmbFileTypes.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        private void PopulateComboList()
        {
            cmbFileTypes.Items.AddRange(FileTypes.GetFileTypes());
        }

        private void btnDest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dr = folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();

            if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                _destFolder = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
                txtDestFolder.Text = _destFolder;
            }
        }

        private void btnStartSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolStripStatusInfo.Visible = true;
            btnStartSearch.Enabled = false;
            fileListView.Items.Clear();
            fileListView.Refresh();
            _selectedFileType = cmbFileTypes.SelectedItem.ToString();

            List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
            DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(drive => drive.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed).ToArray();

            try
            {
                foreach (DriveInfo d in drives)
                {
                    DriveInfo dInfo = d;
                    //Task searchTask = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => { Fi}, _ct.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
                    Task searchTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { FindFiles(dInfo.RootDirectory, ref files); }
                                                                            , _ct.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
                                                                            , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("currently reading" + d.RootDirectory.FullName);
                    taskList.Add(searchTask);

                    searchTask.ContinueWith(PopulateResultList, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

                }

                Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(taskList.ToArray(), OnSearchCompleted, _ct.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {

            }


        }

        private void OnSearchCompleted(Task[] tasks)
        {
            // hide notifier label
            toolStripStatusInfo.Visible = false;
            btnStartSearch.Enabled = true;
            btnZip.Enabled = true;
            toolStripStatusLabel.Text = string.Format("Total files found: {0}", files.Count);
        }

        private List<string> SearchFiles()
        {
            // DirectoryInfo dirSource = new DirectoryInfo(_sourceToSearch);
            _selectedFileType = cmbFileTypes.SelectedItem.ToString();
            return files;
        }

        private void FindFiles(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, ref List<string> files)
        {
            FileSystemAccessRule rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, FileSystemRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);

            try
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo d in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
                {
                    //d.GetAccessControl().ResetAccessRule(rule);
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("currently reading> " + d.FullName);
                    FindFiles(d, ref files);
                }

                files.AddRange(directoryInfo.GetFiles(string.Format("*.{0}", _selectedFileType), SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(finfo => finfo.FullName));
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException excep)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(excep.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return; // MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }

        }

        private void PopulateResultList(Task searchedTask)
        {
            // fill up list view
            fileListView.Items.AddRange(files.Select(fileName => new ListViewItem { Checked = true, Text = fileName }).ToArray());
            toolStripStatusLabel.Text = string.Format("Total files found so far: {0}", files.Count);
        }

        private void btnZip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: You don't have to add `finally` block in each `try/catch` i.e: empty `finally { }` block and `finally { return ; }` at the end of the method will do nothing.

Comment: is think WPF or Win Forms? I will update your sample accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You are doing some pretty heavy [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) processing with the `FindFiles` function.  If you are starting somewhere low in your directory structure, you are probably going to see some slow processing...

Depending on what you need to do, you may not be able to avoid this.  Can you try putting a break point before and after the first call to `FindFiles` and see if that is the problem area.

Answer (score 1):

You are starting the tasks using the current task scheduler, which In this case is using the message loop.

As such, when the message loop starts processing that task, it'll block until completed.

Try to avoid specifying the task scheduler, and it should spin up new threads for your tasks.

Comment: Hi Lasse, thanks for response, actually if I don't use Scheduler then I get cross thread exception.

Comment: You need to use that scheduler for any tasks that will interact with the ui. The find-task doesn't, so don't specify a scheduler for those task, but do for the task(s) that update the ui.

Comment: However, when you drop the task scheduler and get threads instead, your reference to the common list to place files into will break, since it isn't thread-safe. My advice would be to learn a lot more about threading before taking the plunge. Multi-threading is still one of the hardest things to do correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to set up a background worker (or some other `DoWork()` threading scheme).  Here's [an article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/) from the inestimable Jon Skeet that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following line of code inside any loop that has intensive processing

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

This avoids using multiple threads and keeps the form responsive. However, you have to be careful to disable/re-enable any buttons that you don't want the user to click while the job is running.

Threads are generally considered a better way to handle the unresponsiveness, but they're more complicated, so this is a nice easy alternative.

If you added the DoEvents to the FindFiles method, you could remove Factory.StartNew and just call FindFiles directly for each task.

Comment: Application.DoEvents() only looks easier; eventually you start running into the various re-entrancy issues that can occur.  Even if you plan for these up-front, someone maintaining the code later can easily break it in very non-obvious ways.  Threading is also quite challenging, but most developers learn to be cautious whenever they see that threads are being used.